# combinations of 2 dict in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

Hy everyone. I have 2 dicts like:

```
dict_in = {
    'a1': {'b': [1, 2], 'c': [4, 5]}, 
    'a2': {'b': [6, 7], 'c': [8, 10]}
}
```

I would like to get output as all possible not duplicated combinations like:

```
res_dict = [   
   {'a1': {b: 1, c: 4}, 'a2': {'b': 6, 'c': 8}},
   {'a1': {b: 2, c: 4}, 'a2': {'b': 6, 'c': 8}},
   {'a1': {b: 1, c: 5}, 'a2': {'b': 6, 'c':8}},
   {'a1': {b: 1, c: 5}, 'a2': {'b': 6, 'c':8}},
   {'a1': {b: 2, c: 5}, 'a2': {'b': 6, 'c':8}},
   {'a1': {b: 1, c: 4}, 'a2': {'b': 7, 'c':8}},
   {'a1': {b: 1, c: 4}, 'a2': {'b': 7, 'c':10}},
   ....
```

Is where any suggestion?

Comment: (1) Do not name a variable `dict`, that's a built in type name.  (2) Write some code and try it out.  :)

Comment: [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) seems to be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

So, i've find solution:

```
import itertools as it

dict_comb = {i : itertools.product(*dict_in[i].values()) for i in dict_in.keys()}
keys = dict_comb.keys()
final_dict = itertools.product(* [ dict_comb[key] for key in keys])
```

Comment: [your code doesn't correspond](http://ideone.com/SY3jsE) to the output in your question.